# Regex, preg match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

OK, I want to read a table from a website(exchange rate)
I'm trying to read some data from the following lines:

```
<table width="100%" border="0"
```

I get a copy of above lines and with the following lines I can read the data that I want from the address that I placed the copy of that table.

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/");

preg_match('#">([0-9,.]*)<.*">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);
preg_match('#">([0-9,.]*)<.*">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $EURmatch);
preg_match('#">([0-9,.]*)<.*">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $GBPmatch);

$eur = $EURmatch[2];
$usd = $USDmatch[2];
$gbp = $GBPmatch[2];

echo "EUR: $eur USD: $usd GBP: $gbp";
```

But  with the same lines, I can't read the table from source!
Could you please advice me to find my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: In  PHP, you can extract the node values easily with DOMDocument.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What specifically is your question?  What specifically is the issue?

Comment: I just edited the post and provide more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From more exchange it turns out that some detail of the redundant specifications caused a mismatch.

Tray the following replacement. It will work:

```
preg_match('#MonetaryCode">USD.*MonetaryBuy">([0-9,.]*)<.*MonetarySell">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);
preg_match('#MonetaryCode">EUR.*MonetaryBuy">([0-9,.]*)<.*MonetarySell">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $EURmatch);
preg_match('#MonetaryCode">GBP.*MonetaryBuy">([0-9,.]*)<.*MonetarySell">([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $GBPmatch);

$eur = $EURmatch[2];
$usd = $USDmatch[2];
$gbp = $GBPmatch[2];
```

I just shortened the regexp and eliminated unnecessary groupings. The remarks about greedyness and linebreaks have all been illguided. You already had the proper modifiers thatt I just overlooked in the long rexep pattern strings. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that `[^.]` does not match a dot.

Comment: If not a character class reference, then it is matchin _anything but dot_, including line end characters. Removing anyway, as it lacked an explantion in the first lace.

Comment: I provide more explanations, could you please advice me? Please tell me briefly and clearly. Thanks

Comment: Could you please write at least one line of preg_match? I can't get you what do you mean exactly. Thanks

Comment: `preg_match('#<td align="center" class="MonetaryCode">USD</td>(.*\\r?\\n){1,3<td align="center" class="MonetaryBuy">([0-9\.]*)</td><td align="center" class="MonetarySell">([0-9\.]*)</td>#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);` assuming up to three lines from currency code element to values element.

Comment: **Watch for `}` I missed to type in previous comment!!!**    Nevertheless, as you have several currency / value structures you really do not want greedy regexps.   You might want more like `preg_match('#<td align="center" class="MonetaryCode">USD</td>([^M]*M[^M]*)<td align="center" class="MonetaryBuy">([0-9\.]*)</td><td align="center" class="MonetarySell">([0-9\.]*)</td>#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);`  Background: in your sample there is a single capital M between currency elelemt and data item (from MonetaryText). The next MonetarySell/Buy group is what you are looking for then.

Comment: Thanks, I think you did so important correction that I missed them in my code. but it's also doesn't work, I really get confused, I don't know what is the reason, I did what ever you mentioned. If you check the exchange rate numbers, you'll find a comma between them, I also made correction for that by changing ([0-9,]*) instead of ([0-9\.]*) but it didn't work.
Have a look on my lines:
http://clcup.com/regex.txt
I also uploaded the html file of table on the following address:
http://clcup.com/table.html
and the php index for result is on:
http://clcup.com/index.php

Comment: A quick analysis of the failing data exhibits: it is using `'` (sngle quotes) instead of `"` (double quotes) for delimiters. So, replace any occurrence of `"` within your regexp strings by `.` (dot) and it will match again.

Comment: Thanks for reply @rpy, how is it possible? I used from the same table, I get a copy from the table of o-xe.com and paste it into html file into my host. So I think there should not be any different between delimiters. the regexp work perfectly with the table in my host. But it can't read the same table from the original source(o-xe.com).
Anyway I replaced all double quotes with . (dot) as bellow line:
preg_match('#MonetaryCode.>USD.*MonetaryBuy.>([0-9,.]*)<.*MonetarySell.>([0-9,.]*)<#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);

But it did not work!

Comment: Just tried myself to get the data from the original source. It fails with "redirection limit reached". Doing the fetch with curl however returns proper data. When you say _it did not work_, is using php on the original source failing ar the script failing on an existing copy of the (expected) data?

Comment: The reason for the http error using php is a redirect to `/404.html` that itself cauases a redirect to the very same file. This looks like a clear indication that the target site does not like php clients reading data.

Comment: Hahaaa...! Really? Is that because of the original source? Ooooh, So do you know any other way rather than regexp to read data from the original source?

Comment: You should recognize this problem from an error message issued by php. It indicates that your php script is not a problem at all. This is an administrative restriction from the maintainers of the site.Maybe they want to get paid for programmatic service? Could you try saving the result from access using something different (like curl or browser). Does the script wotk with the resulting saved page? Could you recognize the error message? If both times yes, then you would need to hide the fact that you are using php, or probly use a different mechanism for retrieving the page content.

Comment: Dear rpy, Anyway, I you mentioned the correct structure for regex and the script worked perfectly on my side. As you said, I have problem from the original source. As I know, they don't have any paid plan for any of their services and I don't know why they blocked this method. Anyway, I'm interested to get in touch with you and as I'm new in stackoverflow.com, I don't know how can I do that? Is there anyway that I can get in touch with you directly? Maybe I want to ask you to find some way and do this thing for me?